# Changing the Woocommerce breadcrumb menu

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Currently I making changes to Woocommerce's breadcrumb menu. I’m trying to get it to look like this:

```
            <div>
                <ul class="crumbs">
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://localhost:8888/sitename">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="separator"> | </li>
                    <li>About us</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I have this in my functions.php:

```
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'jk_woocommerce_breadcrumbs' );
            function jk_woocommerce_breadcrumbs() {
            return array(
            'delimiter' => ' &#124; ',
            'wrap_before' => '<div itemprop="breadcrumb"><ul class="crumbs"><li>',
            'wrap_after' => '</li></ul></div>',
            'before' => '',
            'after' => '',
            'home' => _x( 'Home', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce' ),
            );
            }
```

Which unfortunately gives me:

```
            <div>
                <ul class="crumbs">
                    <li>
                    <a class="" href="http://localhost:8888/sitename">Home</a>
                    |
                    <a href="http://localhost:8888/sitename/product-category/buzsaws/">buzsaws</a>
                    | Animal Train
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

What can I add to the filter to make it fall inline with the breadcrumb nag that I have showing on the rest of my site?

Thanks,

Comment: I would use a pseudo class and put the sep in the content style.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to display a delimiter would be a CSS-border (like [Aibrean](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/54458/aibrean) suggested). But you can set up the filter to fit your needs:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'custom_woocommerce_breadcrumbs' );
function custom_woocommerce_breadcrumbs() {
  return array(
    'delimiter'   => '<li class="separator"> | </li>',
    'wrap_before' => '<div><ul class="crumbs">',
    'wrap_after'  => '</ul></div>',
    'before'      => '<li>',
    'after'       => '</li>',
    'home'        => _x( 'Home', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce' ),
  );
}
```

Update: To keep your HTML-markup clean and semantic you would leave the delimiter empty like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'custom_woocommerce_breadcrumbs' );
function custom_woocommerce_breadcrumbs() {
  return array(
    'delimiter'   => '', // no delimiter
    'wrap_before' => '<div><ul class="crumbs">',
    'wrap_after'  => '</ul></div>',
    'before'      => '<li>',
    'after'       => '</li>',
    'home'        => _x( 'Home', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce' ),
  );
}
```

And add a border or some similar styling in your `style.css`:

```
.crumbs li {
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.crumbs li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sven,

The CSS bit sounds great but due to the list structure (and lack of sleep) I can't see how I would do it?

Comment: @Nsokyi I've added it to my answer :)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now, that will work too.